# How do you create variables to open up the same type of div?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am making a website that displays profiles of people. Each person is designated a svg button and when that button is clicked, a pop up displays that persons information.

I have this jquery function:

```
$('.button1').click(function() {
    $('.person1-profile').fadeIn();
});

$('.button1-exit').click(function() {
    $('.person1-profile').fadeOut();
});


$('.button2').click(function() {
    $('.person2-profile').fadeIn();
});

$('.button2-exit').click(function() {
    $('.person2-profile').fadeOut();
});


$('.button3').click(function() {
    $('.person3-profile').fadeIn();
});

$('.button3-exit').click(function() {
    $('.person3-profile').fadeOut();
});
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to do this with Javascript so that it significantly shortens the coding, and rather than copy & pasting that code every time for each person, if variables can be made for people/profile and so it would be something like:

```
$('var person + button').click(function() {
    $('var person + profile').fadeIn();
});

$('var button + exit').click(function() {
    $('var person + profile').fadeOut();
});
```

Thank you I really appreciate it! Sorry if it is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data-attributes for this one:

Define your buttons like that:

```
<button class="openButton" data-person="3">Open</button>
<button class="closeButton" data-person="3">Close</button>
```

And your open/close-code like that:

```
$('.openButton').click(function() {
    var personNumber = $(this).attr("data-person");
    $('.person'+personNumber+"-profile").fadeIn();
});

$('.closeButton').click(function() {
    var personNumber = $(this).attr("data-person");
    $('.person'+personNumber+"-profile").fadeOut();
});
```

In action:  http://jsfiddle.net/ndx4fn9n/

Comment: Good approach, but why not delegate the handler to an ancestor and attach a single listener? The close button doesn't need to resolve the person at all, it just closes the related dialogue (presumably it's in the dialogue).

Comment: Good idea - I'm sure there is a lot of room for improvement. But I think the approach with data-attributes is definitely the right one here.

Comment: Much, much, much better approach. That's what the classes are for - to attach a single rule/handler to many elements.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That really helped. After reading about all the different types of variables in Javascript (which I'm not used to working with) I couldn't figure it out. Great answer.

Comment: Also, when you have only one element with a given class, try using `ID` attribute instead - should be faster. Or simply consider improving the solution by doing what @RobG suggested.

Comment: @MichalLeszczyk—the fun with classes is that the OP might only have one now, but can add multiple later. It also becomes more generic. But horses for courses. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your selector:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName(svgButtonSelector);
for (i = 0; i > buttons.length; i++) {
    $(".button" + index).click(function() {
        $(".person" + index + "-profile").fadeIn();
    });
}
```

This will attach the event to every svg button you've got on your page. You just gotta make sure the scope of selection for the buttons is declared right (I'm using `document` as an example).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of few ways of doing it.

You could read only 7th character of the class name. This limits you to having only 10 fields. Or you could put id on very end like this `person-profile1` and read 16th and up character.

You could also set up additional tag to your container. But this will cause your web page to not HTML validate.

```
<div class="person" personid="1">// content</div>
```

Comment: The idea is fine, but the execution - not so much :) See @Johannes Reuter answer - you can use `data-attributes`. This way your markup is still valid.